# how to split a unordered list into two in html and css

Tags: html, css, list

ok, this problem has been with me for 2 weaks, and now i'm giving up and asking for help

what i need to do is make a new line in a unordered list inside of a div
this is what i'm aiming for

> Home Contact Us Education
>
> FAQ Stores Services

and with my currnet code i'm getting this

> Home Contact Us Education
> FAQ Stores Services

i have tried methods like float and center but nothing is working

please help me, i'm going to lost hair at this point....
thanks

Comment: Use `<br>` for a line break?

Comment: can you add html code??

Comment: line breaks do the exact same thing

Comment: Html code if possible??

Comment: we can't help fix your current code if we can't see it

Comment: What they said. Also, I have no idea why you think methods like float and center would help in creating line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qabZqm

Basically it does this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Stores</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
li:nth-child(4):after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
/* tag within the li for styling purposes */
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

with :nth-child(4) I add a pseudoelement that creates a break (\A).
The A Tag in the li is to add some styling (because of display inline the LIs cant be styled with margins etc...)... and I think thought this is a menu :-)